# iOS - Submitting Build 1.7 For Version 1.0 Application

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have prerelease builds for my app that my team has tested in Test Flight. I'd like to upload my most recent prerelease build (1.7) to submit the app for review as a version 1.0. Is there a difference between the version number of a prerelease build and the version number of the app that I want to submit for review by Apple? Will this keep my app at version 1.0 or will it be listed on the app store as version 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build number and the version number are different. There are two spaces in Xcode, one for version number and one for build number. The version number is what matters when submitting your app to the app store. In [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH38-SW1), you can see they increment the build number by one to differentiate between different versions for test flight.

Comment: So if I have a prerelease version of my app that I've tested in Test Flight, version 1.7, build 1, and I want to upload this, it will show up on the App Store as version 1.7? I have a prerelease version 1.0 build 1, but it's when the app was in its beginning stages. How do I get around this? Can't I just upload a new prerelease version 1.0 with the build number as 2 so I can upload that for review to make sure it shows up as version 1.0 in the app store?

Comment: @Rafi Yeah you can do that. When submitting your app, you will have to select whatever build you want to submit to the app store, so as long as you pick the build you want to submit then it doesn't really matter what build number it is.

Comment: Awesome, I thought that work around was too good to be true, but it worked! Thanks for the info! :D

Answer (score 0):

Hello @rafi.
You have to remember their was version number in two places one in your bundle and another in your iTunes account.
Build number is not shown in app store.
The version number you entered in iTunes account is shown in app store.

Happy coding :)